# Dataframe method to Transpose multiple rows to single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

How can i transpose multiple rows to a single column.

**** my rows contain a word 'Narrative', so there are many similar words.
if the word 'Narrative' is found then I want to transpose it to a single column.

example input [input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBf5l.png)

OUTPUT [needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dsje.png)

[original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Beo.png)

Updated
[image: updated example]

Comment: hi! please share text instead of images to make it easier for us to help you. also please show anything you've tried

Comment: Please don't use image because it's not reproducible. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, from now i will add text

Comment: I am facing difficulty to  make a text table, please consider updated image

Answer (score 0):

Find rows and where `x == 'narrative'` and move them to columns:

```
idx = df[df['x'] == 'narrative'].index
df1 = df.drop(idx).assign(narrative=df.loc[idx, 'y'].values).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   x  y  z narrative
0  a  b  c         A
1  d  a  b         B
```

Comment: Hi corralien, some times the word 'narrative' is in consecutive rows. if I applied this logic and getting Value Error: Length of values does not match length of index. How can I bypass this issue.

Comment: Update an input sample and the expected output. I'll try to answer it.